# placing affiliate tracking tags on jquery ui tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery ui tabs on a page in my jquery driven asp.net c# web application. The tabs seperate out the content nicely giving the experience to the user that they are moving across multiple pages.

I have a third party affiliate company who need to track users actions and therefore want to place pixel tags on each of the pages ("tabs").

If I add the tags directly to each tab, then it wont track correctly as all will get fired on page load.

I was thinking of loading the image on the fly using the java script as the user moves through the tabs. Is this the best approach and if so how can I achieve this? Any other suggestions. Sample of what needs to be included per tab as the user moves through them is:

```
Tab 1: <img src="https://xxxxx.com/xxxx.html?p=xxxx&d=1" width="0" height="0" />
Tab 2: <img src="https://xxxxx.com/xxxx.html?p=xxxx&d=2" width="0" height="0" />
Tab 3: <img src="https://xxxxx.com/xxxx.html?p=xxxx&d=3" width="0" height="0" />
Tab 4: <img src="https://xxxxx.com/xxxx.html?p=xxxx&d=4" width="0" height="0" />
```

I would like to put some structure in place that I could easily add further tags to be loaded per ui tab seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the images in their respective tabs, but keep their src attribute empty. Put the link to the image in the HTML5 "data" attribute.

Then, when the tab is selected, load the image:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second Tab</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third Tab</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        <img class="affiliate" src="" height="0" width="0" data-src="https://xxxxx.com/xxxx.html?p=xxxx&d=1" />
        <p>The tabs contents goes here.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        <img class="affiliate" src="" height="0" width="0" data-src="https://xxxxx.com/xxxx.html?p=xxxx&d=2" />
        <p>The tabs contents goes here.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        <img class="affiliate" src="" height="0" width="0" data-src="https://xxxxx.com/xxxx.html?p=xxxx&d=3" />
        <p>The tabs contents goes here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, when you create the tabs, pass in a select event handler to load those images.

**Javascript**:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    select: function(event, ui)
    {
        $(ui.panel).find('img.affiliate').each(function()
        {
            $(this).attr( 'src', $(this).data('src') );
        });
    }
});
```